# What is the melodic minor scale with a flattened 5 called?

Tags: theory, scales, terminology, modes

I can't find the answer anywhere on the internet. Except for that it can be seen as a whole-half scale with the sixth note left out. However this explanation doesn't satisfy my desire for an official name. Does anyone know what this scale is called?

Comment: A scale w/ the Tritone built in?  ouch  :-)

Comment: Will do for some good experimentation :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at it as mode of the [Romanian major scale](http://pianoencyclopedia.com/scales/romanian-major/C-romanian-major.html) which if built on C results in the scale:

```
C Db E F# G A Bb
```

If you started on the G you would get the scale you describe:

```
G A Bb C Db E F#
```

It's not really a common scale so there's not really an exact name. If you needed to call it something I would go with melodic minor 5b due to the fact it is one note off from the melodic minor scale, but just calling it the 5th mode of Romanian major scale would also work.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Although the source is a little indecisive about it being a heptatonic or an octatonic scale. I guess that would be a slip of the pen and it's just heptatonic?

Comment: @Olesma it's  heptatonic, it has 7 notes in the scale.

Answer (score 1):

Ascending Melodic Minor flat five scale has two names:

1) Jeth's Mode

2) Jazz Minor b5

It is the 5th mode of Romanian Major Scale.
Romanian Major Scale is also known as Lydian Dominant b9 Scale

Answer (score -1):

Romanian Major Scale: C, Db, E, F#, G, A, Bb, (C)

1st Mode: Romanian Major Scale (aka Lydian Dominant b9)

2nd Mode: Super Lydian Augmented ♮6

3rd Mode: Locrian ♮2 bb7

4th Mode: Super Locrian bb6

5th Mode: Jazz Minor b5 (aka Jeth's Mode)

6th Mode: Javanese b4

7th Mode: Lydian Augmented b3

Comment: Welcome to Music Stack Exchange.  The site welcomes focused and on target answers and questions.  Unfortunately I believe either you have misunderstood the original poster's question or have made an error or two in constructing your answer.  For one thing, the OP specifies a flattened fifth.  In your answer, the scale you call Romanian Major does not have a flattened fifth.  At no point do you mention Melodic Minor, which is what the OP is asking about.  Perhaps you need to clarify your answer to show how it relates to the question.  In any event, again, Welcome to the site.