# Name for minor scale with flat fifth

Tags: scales

I'm looking for a name for the minor scale with a flattened fifth note.

> WHWWHWW -> WHWHWWW

> C min: C D Eb F G Ab Bb; C ???: C D Eb F Gb Ab Bb

The closest my searching has come to an answer was [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-melodic-minor-scale-with-a-flattened-5-called) SE:PT question of the same name (and yet not the same question?).

Comment: Apologies if this question is simple or asked elsewhere. I fiddle with keys and not really study the theories and relationships behind them. I might be lacking the terminology to search for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the other correct answers here...

- It's the third mode of the [Lydian dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_scale) (or Acoustic) scale.

Lydian dominant = `C - D - E - F# - G - A - Bb - C` = WWWHWHW

Thus the third mode = `E - F# - G - A - Bb - C - D - E` = WHWHWWW

Or, transposed: `C - D - Eb - F - Gb - Ab - Bb - C`

[Ian Ring](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/1749) explains:

> Identical to Lydian but for its lowered seventh; this scale is named Lydian Dominant because its 1-3-5-7 members form a dominant seventh chord. The name "Acoustic" is more common, the name refers to its similarity to the eighth through 14th partials in the harmonic series. For this reason it is also known at the "overtone scale".

Ian Ring's site contains a list of names for this scale, including those used in Carnatic music.

- It's also called the [Half-diminished](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_diminished_scale) scale ().
- [William Zeiter](http://allthescales.org/search.php) has given this scale the name "Lythian", the second mode of "Larian".
  [image: Image of Larian scale and modes]

Answer (score 4):

> C D Eb F Gb Ab Bb

It's 6th mode of melodic minor scale (it has the same notes as Eb melodic minor).

Answer (score 3):

Putting the notes into a better known order gives the *melodic* minor, rising (or the *jazz melodic* minor. E♭ F G♭ A♭ B♭ C D.

Keeping the same order but starting on its 6th note gives a mode of that. C D E♭ F G♭ A♭ B♭.

This mode has a couple of names - **Aeolian ♭5** and **Locrian ♯2**.

Comment: Rather locrian ♮2, not #2.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom of your question has been answered correctly. Just to help and give some additional information referring to your comment:

> *I fiddle with keys and not really study the theories and relationships behind them. I might be lacking the terminology to search for*.

The lacking term you have to look for is:   **the modes**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music)

and if you are interested in modern scale theory:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_scale

Comment: *Modes*. Huh, modes are interesting. It's interesting that you can change the tonic and get something functionally different. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

I know this scale as "locrian ♮2"